# How to take the mean of a vector no matter what is inside?

Tags: c++

I'm working on a homework problem that requires me to find the basic statistics on data-classes. I'm currently working on finding the mean but not sure how to set it up because of the way the given files are structured.

Here is what I was given:

```
/* Copyright 2018 test_stat_tracker.cc */

#include <cstddef>
// using size_t
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

#include "../hw7/stat_tracker.h"
using csce240::StatTracker;


const int kInt_elems[] = {1, 2, 1, 5, 7, 2, 9};
const size_t kInt_elem_count = 7;
const int kInt_elem_mean = 3;  // actually 27/7
const int kInt_elem_median = 2;
const int kInt_elem_mode[] = {1, 2};


/* Calculates the actual mean, prints the expected and actual values, and
 *   returns whether they are the same.
 */
template <class T>
bool TestMean(const StatTracker<T>& tracker, const T& expected) {
  T actual = tracker.Mean();
  cout << "Expected mean: " << expected
      << ", Actual mean: " << actual;
  return actual == expected;
}

void TestIntStats() {
  vector<int> elems;
  elems.assign(kInt_elems, kInt_elems + kInt_elem_count);

  StatTracker<int> tracker;
  for (auto it = elems.begin(); it != elems.end(); ++it)
    tracker.Add(*it);

  if (!TestMean(tracker, kInt_elem_mean))
    cout << ": FAILED\n";
  else
    cout << ": PASSED\n";
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  TestIntStats();

  return 0;
}
```

Now this is what I have managed in my .h and .cc files:

```
/* Copyright 2018
 *
 * stat_tracker.h 
 */    

#ifndef _HW7_STAT_TRACKER_H_  // NOLINT
#define _HW7_STAT_TRACKER_H_  // NOLINT
#include <ostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
using std::accumulate;

namespace csce240 {

template <class T>
class StatTracker  {
 public:
  const T Mean() const;  // T = T + T and T = T / int must be defined
  // T a, b; a += b; DON'T DO THIS
};
}  // namespace csce240

#include "../hw7/stat_tracker.cc"  // comment out

#endif /* _HW7_STAT_TRACKER_H_ */  // NOLINT
```

And my .cc file

```
/* Copyright 2018
 *
 * stat_tracker.cc 
 */
// #include "stat_tracker.h"  // NOLINT
namespace csce240 {

template<class T>
const T StatTracker<T>::Mean() const {
  auto v(elems);
  vector<T> v = accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0)/v.size();
  return T();
}

}  // namespace csce240

#include "stat_tracker.h"
```

At the moment I am working on getting the mean to work, but I keep receiving an error that `elems` was not declared. I can't initialize `kInt_elems` in my `.cc` because my professor will be using his own test class with different numbers.

I am very lost and need a little direction on how to set up this function.

Comment: This is a staggering amount of code for us to review. Can you boil this down to a more *minimal* example that demonstrates the precise nature of your problem?

Comment: This looks somewhat overcomplicated to me.

Comment: @tadman I have simplified the code to what I'm asking

Comment: `vector<T> v = accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0)/v.size();` accumulate has a nasty pitfall in that the return type is deduced from the last parameter, hence you should not use a `0` there (and it does not return a vector)

Comment: the only `elems` i can find is a local variable to some other method, i guess the `StatTracker` should keep a copy or reference of the data to analyse

Comment: btw its good to know that you have functions for testing, but I dont think they are related to the problem, cant you remove them? Please read about [mcve]

Comment: well, I read again and actually the test method has a critical hint: `tracker.Add(*it);` you should implement an `Add` method to add the elements to be analysed later. Either make it simply push the elements to a vector that you have to add as member, or already do some of the calculations while adding elements (eg the sum)

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that calculates the mean of a vector.
Restrictions:

1. Data type must support addition.
2. Data type must support division.
3. Data type must support assignment of zero.

The Code:

```
   template <typename Data>
    Data Mean(const std::vector<Data>& v)
    {
      Data sum = 0;
      const size_t length = v.length();
      for (size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
      {
        sum += v[i];
      }
      return sum / length;
    }
```

This uses the primitive `for` loop to sum up the elements in the vector.

The result depends on how division is defined for the data type.  For example, floating point will return a different result than an integral type.